# Get list of chrome extensions allowed in Incognito Mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, menubar, firefox-addon-webextensions, incognito-mode

By using chrome API it is available to get list of all installed extensions.

I am using this code:

```
chrome.management.getAll(function (list) {
    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var extension = list[i];
        console.log(extension); // contains id, enabled, name, version, type, ...
    }
});
```

The problem is, extensions can be allowed to run in Incognito Mode. But there is no property to check if a specified extension is allowed?

I need to know if user is in incognito mode, and a specified extension is enable, is it allowed in incognito mode too?

As a final bullet, Get a list of icons in menu bar can do the trick (Not allowed extension will not show in menubar) but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To know if user is in incognito mode, inject a content script and call [`chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#property-inIncognitoContext) should help; as for detect the state of other extensions, seems no workarounds at present.

Comment: Sad news :( . And no solution for get the list of all icons in menubar?